# Understanding the expression in Python

Tags: python

I an new to Python and do not understand the following expression

```
tasks = [
            {
                'id': 1,
                'title': u'Buy groceries',
                'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
                'done': False
            },
            {
                'id': 2,
                'title': u'Learn Python',
                'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
                'done': False
            }
         ]
```

and then

```
task = filter(lambda t: t['id'] == task_id, tasks)
if len(task) == 0:
    abort(404)
return jsonify( { 'task': task[0] } )
```

I do not fully understand the `filter(lambda t:t['id']==task_id,tasks)` portion of the code. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Can you point us to the parts of the [documentation for filter()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#filter) you have trouble understanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lambda t:t['id']==task_id` Is a function which returns a boolean. If `t['id']` equals `task_id`, then the lambda will return True.

[`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) goes through each element of `tasks`, assigning it to `t`. If the boolean is `True`, then it will remain in the returned list. If it is `False`, it is not included in the new list. I.E, it's *filtered*.

In other words, it's the same as `[t for t in tasks if t['id'] == task_id]`

---

Here's another example:

```
>>> mylist = range(10)
>>> filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, mylist)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

This finds all the even numbers between 1 and 10.

It's also equivalent to:

```
>>> mylist = range(10)
>>> [x for x in mylist if x % 2 == 0]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```